# WordPress WooCommerce Polylang перевод слова "(optional)" на странице оплаты

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

На моём сайте WordPress есть магазин WooCommerce, для перевода сайта использую Polylang. Мне нужно перевести страницу оплаты.

Я нашёл php файл php, где это делается. Сделал весь перевод, но появилась проблема с одной строчкой.
Там можно сделать перевод фразы "Order notes", но я не знаю как перевести  "(optional)".
[image]
[image]

Comment: Какую-то ты ерунду мутишь, это стандартные текста вуккоммерс. Они уже все переведены и при смене языка меняются все текста)

Comment: Ерунда? Ничего не переводится, при смене языка. Ты думаешь я бы писал, если бы всё переводилось?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что "(optional)" это переводиться (не обязательно), а это значит, что данное слово может употребляется не только в WooCommerce, а и в самом WordPress. Установи плагин loco translate. Он отлично работает с Polylang. Он тебе отобразит все темы и плагины (и сам WordPress). Для начала, выбери плагин WooCommerce, далее "Редактировать Русский язык" и в поиске напиши "optional". Если найдется, то ниже впиши перевод.

Comment: LocoTranslate разве работает с Polylang? Это же два разных плагина, для перевода.

Comment: Смело пользуйтесь. Да это 2 разных плагина, но конфликтов они не дают.